# Software switching audio device Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have an issue with my sound devices. I have  front audio panel and rear on my PC. I have dynamics plugged in front and headphones in back panel. Sometimes I need to change output from one device to another. By default with plugged both devices I can listen sound only from dynamics. If I want to hear something from headphones I can't do it without unplugging my dynamics from front panel. I see two  output devices in Ubuntu settings, but only one is working.

I've also tried to increase sound in alsamixer, but it didn't help.
I've attached a screenshot with sound devices.

[image: sound devices]

Is it possible to switch outputs by software?

Results of `pactl info`:

```
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 34
Server Protocol Version: 34
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 17
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: gzimin
Host Name: gzimin-MS-7A38
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 14.2
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_2b_00.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_2b_00.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: c4f3:d0db
```

Comment: Which sound devices from the list are you trying to switch between?  I see 3 listed there, but from the sounds of it, are both working when 'headphones' are selected?

Comment: Thanks for response @rtaft. I was trying to choose any of them, but only one will work. Other have no sound.

Comment: It's likely a hardware limitation.  The audio jacks in the front and back of the PC go to the same sound card.

Comment: So, seems like to fix this I need to buy audio-card?
BTW I can freely switch output devices on Windows 10, but Ubuntu can't do this.

Comment: What do you see in Windows?  is it the same card switching from front to back ports in the UI?  If you are able to control it in Windows then there should be a software/driver way to solve this, whether it exists for your specific card needs to be determined.

Comment: I can freely change device output in Windows. If you want to know concrete names, I can post it later. I can see in Windows 2 devices two, and switching them will switch my sound output. Without any un-plugging.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the Gnome shell extension [Sound input and output device chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/). In the settings of the extension, you have the option to select the device.

Comment: It gives me the same options as in the ubuntu settings. It doesn't help me.